# ggplot2 - how to move geom_rug to avoid overriding points

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have created a basic scatterplot with ggplot2 and added a rug with geom_rug on the y-axis (left side) to it, however the rug is hiding a few points. I have tried position_dodge, position_jitterdodge and hjust in order to move the rug and make those points visible, but it did not give the desired result. I can't move the rug to the right side of the plot, since it will be hiding points here as well.

Is there a way to move the rug on the other side of the y-axis, outside of the plot?

Here is some example code:

```
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point(alpha=0.8)+ 
geom_rug(aes(x=NULL, y=poptotal), alpha=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply expanding the x-axis limits, using

```
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.01,0.01))
```